# 英語の文章を大体の文字数で、スペースのところで区切る方法

Tags: ruby

900字程度の英語の文章があるとします。

これを300文字ずつで区切りたいのですが、英語だとスペースのところで区切らないと単語が途中で切れてしまいます。

正確に300文字で区切る必要はなく、3００文字前後で大丈夫なので、Rubyで出来るだけ短いコードやgemなどで単語が途中で切れない形で文章を分割する方法を教えてもらえないでしょうか？

Comment: 例えば `arr = text.scan(/.{1,300}[ \t,.]/m)` でしょうか。ただ、この場合には `"`(ダブルクォート)や `'`(シングルクォート)で囲まれた文字列がその範囲内で分割されてしまう事があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます！ 300文字後の一番最初の半角スペースを見つければよいのですね！！！助かりました！

Comment: コメントで解決した場合は解決した内容を質問者が回答として投稿し承認してください。

Answer (score 1):

ちょっと大げさですが、Railsのactionviewにある[ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper#word_wrap](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-word_wrap)を使うという手もあります。Railsを使っているのであれば、素直にこっちを使った方が良いかと思います。

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
require 'action_view'
include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper

sample_str = <<EOS
We are about to study the idea of a computational process. Computational processes are abstract beings that inhabit computers. As they evolve, processes manipulate other abstract things called data. The evolution of a process is directed by a pattern of rules called a program. People create programs to direct processes. In effect, we conjure the spirits of the computer with our spells.
EOS

wrapped_str = word_wrap(sample_str, line_width: 40)
puts wrapped_str
```

※ サンプルテキストはSICPの第1章冒頭より引用

Comment: ありがとうございます！確かにこちらを使うとシンプルですね！！！

Answer (score 0):

metroplisさんに回答頂きましたので共有いたします

例えば arr = text.scan(/.{1,300}[ \t,.]/m) でしょうか。ただ、この場合には "(ダブルクォート)や '(シングルクォート)で囲まれた文字列がその範囲内で分割されてしまう事があります。

Answer (score 0):

```
def ans(list, str, split_size, split_hope_size)
  if !str[split_size-1]
    list << str
  elsif str[split_size-1] == " "
    ans(list << str[0...split_size], str[split_size...str.size], split_hope_size, split_hope_size)
  else
    ans(list, str, split_size - 1, split_hope_size)
  end
end

ans([], str.gsub("\n", " "), 300, 300).each do |line|
  puts line
end
```